Vmware exporter for Prometheus to scrap VM Disk I/O and NIC Data transfer
I'm looking for any existing prometheus exporters that can fetch a VM's Disk I/O speeds and NIC Data transfer(Rx/Tx) speeds by communicating with vcenter only, so we don't have to install Node_exporters on each VM to get these metrics.
We already tested pryorda/vmware_exporter, which fetches the CPU & Memory metrics, but not detailed Disk/NIC metrics.
